# Is it possible to append to a list via .dir-locals.el?

Tags: directory-local-variables, alists

So, I know that I can assign a variable via `.dir-locals.el`...

```el
("thingy" (1 2 3 4))
```

but is there any way that I can append to an array, if at all?

```el
("that" . "is correct")
(add-to-list 'thingy 5)
```

Comment: You can use `eval`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [GNU Emacs Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Directory-Variables.html):

> You can specify the variables `mode`, `eval`, and `unibyte` in your .dir-locals.el, and they have the same meanings as they would have in file local variables. coding cannot be specified as a directory local variable. See [Local Variables in Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Choosing-Modes.html).

Variables in `.dir-locals.el` are *mode specific*. You have to explicitly specify the mode that you are using, it is not a simple key/value store.

The `eval` keyword means you can execute Lisp code, this means you may call `add-to-list` and modify variables as needed.

```lisp
((org-mode . ((eval . (add-to-list 'org-publish-project-alist
 ("org-project" (:output-dir "~/org-out")))))
```